# Linux: chmod invalid mode

Tags: linux, chmod

I've got this files in a directory ...

[image]

I want to change the permissions of files which others has execution permission. These are the files which I want to change the permissions:

[image]

If I try to change the permissions of these files with this command:

```
ls -l | cut -d ' ' -f 1,9 | grep '\-\-\x' | xargs chmod o+t
```

I've got this error:

[image]

**chmod: invalid mode "-rw-r-S--x, -rw-r-S--x"**

Why I've got this error? How can a I set the sticky bit to these files? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: probs better for Unix SE

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your answer

Comment: not an answer - a suggestion to ask question on Unix SE

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`xargs chmod` just wants the names of the files, but you're giving it the full output of `ls -l`, so it interprets the existing modes as a mode option that makes no sense.  You want something more like

```
ls -l | grep '\-\-\x' | cut -d ' ' -f 9 | xargs chmod o+t
```

to pass just the filenames to `xargs`, but without knowing what you are actually trying to do, its tough to say if this is what you really want.

Comment: If someone is interested in the solution, the correct instruction is: ls –l | cut –d ‘ ‘ –f 1,9 | grep ‘\-\-x’ | cut –d ‘ ‘  -f 2 | xargs chmod o+t